# Java east to west and west to east finder

Tags: java

This code can find a word if it goes from LEFT to RIGHT, how can I change it to find a word from Right to left and from top to bottom?

```
boolean findWE(String word) {
  for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c <= width - word.length(); c++) {
      if (word.charAt(0) == grid[r][c]) {
        boolean failed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && !failed; i++) {
          if (word.charAt(i) != grid[r][c + i]) {
            failed = true;
          }
        }
        if (!failed) {
          System.out.printf("%s found WE at(%d,%d)\n", word, r, c);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: By thinking about it, and changing the program.  If you haven't got the answer yet, then you haven't thought about it enough.  If you solve this yourself, you will learn more and become a better Java programmer ... whether or not this is homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this isn't homework, you should just be able to use the library functions to reverse a String:

```
boolean findEW(String word) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  // Why are your strings stored as a 2-dimensional character array??
  for(int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
    builder.append(grid[r]);
    builder.append("\n");
  }

  builder.reverse();
  return builder.toString().contains(word);
}
```

Or, since finding "abc" in the "edcba" backwards is the same as finding "cba" in "edcba" forwards, you can do the following:

```
boolean findEW(String word) {
  return findWE(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
}
```

Comment: I definitely agree that in real code, this approach would be preferrable. However for learning purposes, it is still beneficial to play around with loops and solve this in a way similar to the style in code passage in the question.

Comment: It should be marked as "homework" then. If it's not, then this answer perfectly solves the problem.